# should I choose docker for isolated development of python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I'm developing some python projects. Has some questions about docker. I used virutalenv for my python development before. Different python version different dependencies with different projects Of course some of the projects need phantomjs selenium such third software. So how should I configure my dockerfile? and how much space will the container cost, and is it efficient to deploy to cloud server?

I know that should there are some cmd shows below in the dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server && apt-get install -y python3.5 && apt-get install -y python-pip && apt-get install blablabla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, Docker is an international software platform for building, shipping, and running applications through a variety of software platforms.
So after installing Docker, you have a couple options for configuring your dockerfile.

You could locate the configuration file, found at 'c:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json
You'll find this information

```
{
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "dns": [],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": [],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "labels": [],
    "log-driver": "", 
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "",
    "graph": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "debug": true,
    "hosts": [],
    "log-level": "",
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "",
    "tlscert": "",
    "tlskey": "",
    "group": "",
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "bridge": "",
    "fixed-cidr": "",
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "insecure-registries": [],
    "disable-legacy-registry": false
}
```

Thus, in the 'host' key configuring the Docker Engine all incoming connects at port 2375 with TCP

```
{
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}
```

You can store specific images and containers in an alternate path as well. If not specified, the default is c:\programdata\docker

```
{    
    "graph": "d:\\docker"
}
```

Otherwise for configuring your dockerfile, you can use the default network and docker security group by locating the configuration file: 'c:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json

```
{
    "bridge" : "none" # sets default network 
}

{
    "group" : "docker" # sets default security
}
```

How much space the container will code depends on the amount of disk space each container takes up. You can find how much space a container takes up with this link: artifacts..appspot.com

Replace  
and run with this: gsutil du gs://artifacts..appspot.com

It's very efficient to deploy to a cloud server because Docker has its underlying Docker Cloud. But first, assuming you installed the Docker Engine (as explained how to configured above) locally, you'll need the docker-cloud CLI. In turn, it's not that difficult to manage. However, just do some research depending on what platform you have to install docker cloud CLI correctly.

( docker run dockercloud/cli -h ) <-- installs CLI image in a container for you, once docker-cloud CLI is installed.

I hope this helps!! :)